# I have an issue with html/js task with 2 div elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are 2 blocks of arbitrary size in html, when you click on one block, this block disappears, and the second size decreases by 20 px and the color changes into blue (in javascript)

Comment: Please share your effort what is you tried so far.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style> 
        #div2
        {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background:yellow;
            transition:width 2s;
            -moz-transition:width 2s; 
            -webkit-transition:width 2s; 
            -o-transition:width 2s; 
        }
        #div1{height:100px;width:100px;background:#ff0000;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>

    <script>
        function getStyle(obj){
            var style = null;
            if (window.getComputedStyle) {
                style = window.getComputedStyle(obj, null);    //not IE
            } else { 
                style = obj.currentStyle;  // IE
            }
            return style;
        }
        var oDiv1 = document.querySelector('#div1');
        var oDiv2 = document.querySelector('#div2');
        oDiv1.onclick = function(){
            this.style.display = 'none';
            var oldW = parseInt(getStyle(oDiv2).width);
            oDiv2.style.width = (oldW + 20) + 'px';
            oDiv2.style.backgroundColor = '#0000ff';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
for (let element of document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper > div')) {
    element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.target.classList.add('hidden');

        const filtered = document.querySelector('.wrapper > div:not(.hidden)');

        filtered.classList.add('filtered');
    });
}
```

SCSS

```
.wrapper {
    & > div {
        width: 64px;
        height: 64px;
        background-color: red;

        &.hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        &.filtered {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```